# application of laws of large numbers

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$, define $Y_n=\min\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\{X_k\}$ and show that $$V_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nY_k}{\log n}\rightarrow 1$$ in probability.

I am trying to compute $EV_n$ first and I think this is an application of laws of large numbers. Any ideas/hint on how to continue solving this question

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that the ratio part I agree, however, how do you obtain the harmonic series? So $EY_n=1+1/2+...+1/n$, How to compute the expectation of the minimum.

Comment: There is no direct application of LLN since $Y_k$ are dependent and not identically distributed. It was shown below that $E(V_n)\to 1$ so you are left to show that $var(V_n)\to 0$ to show convergence to $1$ in $L^2$ and hence in probability. Use [$Cov(Y_k,Y_l)=\frac {k(n-l+1)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mlugo/stat134-f11/order-stats.pdf) for $k\le l$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A start: You may already know that the random variable $Y_k$ has mean $\frac{1}{k+1}$. If you do not, note that $Y_k\gt y$ if and only if all the $X_i$, with $i\le k$, are $\gt y$. For $y$ between $0$ and $1$, this has probability $(1-y)^k$.

Thus $Y_k$ has cdf $1-(1-y)^k$, and therefore density function $k(1-y)^{k-1}$. To find $E(Y_k)$, calculate $\int_0^1 ky(1-y)^{k-1}\,dy$. To evaluate, the change of variable $u=1-y$ is useful. We get $\frac{k}{k}-\frac{k}{k+1}$, which is $\frac{1}{k+1}$.

By the linearity of expectation, we have therefore
$$E(V_n)=\frac{1}{\log n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$
Let $H_i$ be the $i$-th [harmonic number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) Then we can write $E(V_n)$ more compactly as
$$E(V_n)=\frac{H_{n+1}-1}{\log n}.\tag{1}$$
It is standard that  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{\log n}=1$, so (1) has limit $1$.

Comment: Please note that this is only a start. We need to control the variance in order to conclude, say using the Chebyshev Inequality.

Comment: Controlling variance of the sum ($\sim Cn^{-1}$) shows that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-H_n\overset{L^2}\to 0$ which suggests that $\sqrt n (\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-H_n)$ converges in distribution (to a normal?).